# Show fields from new res.partner contact type on inherited module - Odoo v9 community

Tags: python, odoo, qweb

I've inherited the `res.partner` model like this:

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    type = fields.Selection(selection_add=[(('mina', 'Mina'))])
    origen = fields.Char(string="Origen")
    destino = fields.Char(string="Destino")
```

I have added a new type called "mina"

This new type of contact, should show these two fields only, `origen` and `destino`

Tje new radio button is shown on the form, that's Okay, but I can't figure out how to show only those two fields, it just shows the other `type` of contact fields, this is my view:

```
        <record id="view_partner_form_1" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">res.partner.form</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name='inherit_id' ref='base.view_partner_form'/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//form//sheet//group//notebook" position="after">
                <form string="Minas">
                                <sheet>
                                    <field name="type" required="1" widget="radio" options="{'horizontal': true}"/>
                                    <hr/>
                                    <group>
                                        <group attrs="{'invisible': [('type','=', 'mina')]}">
                                        </group>
                                        <group>
                                            <field name="origen" string="Origen" attrs="{'required' : [('type', '=', 'mina')]}"/>
                                            <field name="destino" string="Destino" attrs="{'required' : [('type', '=', 'mina')]}"/>
                                        </group>
                                    </group>
                                </sheet>
                            </form>
                      </xpath>
               </field>
        </record>
```

Any ideas on this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position `after` means that you append more elements to the view, if you want to modify the existing fields, use position `attributes` instead. You could make the other fields invisible using below code:

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='field_name']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': [...]}</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank You